# React Hooks <a onClick> modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

I have a functional react component using hooks. I want to show a modal after clicking the `a` tag before redirecting. I tried `useHistory` to push the route but it does not work. Here is a reduced version of my code

```
const LoginPage = ({ url }) => {
  const handleClick= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;
    showModal();
    // trigger the redirect after closing the modal
  };

  return (
    <a
      href={url}
      onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
    >
      click
    </a>
  );
};
```

Comment: you forgot to invoke it: `preventDefault()`

Comment: It is invoked on my code. Just forgot to add it here

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that with an history push in the onCloseWhatever of your modal

If it's not working you should check your implementation of history

Comment: Im using browserRouter and it redirects to `/home` for example but it's getting the data from my node express backend. It does add the path to the URL but it doesnt go to the page automatically